# getting the selected item scrolled to top of the JList

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jscrollpane, jlist

ensureIndexIsVisible() makes the selected item appear at the end of the JList, so how do i make the selected item appear at the top of the JList instead at the end?

Comment: *"is there a way to get the index of the top element that is currently shown"* I've written GUIs with dozens of lists and never needed that info.  Why do you?

Comment: uhh.....i used ensureIndexIsVisible(), but the one that is selected is getting displayed at the last of JList. I want it to be displayed at the top. Im not a pro in swings, couldnt figure it out how to do that

Comment: That is a comment better edited into the question.  As a general rule, it is better to state the goal (scroll item to center) than the strategy (get index of top-most item).

Comment: yeah, I should have gone straight to the point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Get the height of each item with `list.getFixedCellHeight()`
2. Get the viewport bounds with `scrollpane.getViewport().getViewPosition().y`
3. Divide (2) by (1) to get the number of cells that are hidden, round it, and that's your index.

There may be an easier, built-in way. Check out the API for [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and [JScrollpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

Comment: thank you..that list.getFixedCellHeight() and getting the vertical view position saves the day....

Comment: yeah...there is a simpler solution,using scrollRectToVisible

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
yourList.getFirstVisibleIndex();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i got want i wanted

```
jlist.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
int num;
if(index+1000>datalist.size())
num = datalist.size()-index-1; 
else
num = 1000;
jlist.scrollRectToVisible(jl.getCellBounds(index,index+num));
jlist.setSelectedIndex(index);
```

this made my selected item at index appear at the top of the JList

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but maybe my answer can be useful.

```
myList.setVisibleRowCount(x);
int selected=myList.getSelectedIndex();
myList.scrollRectToVisible(myList.getCellBounds(selected,selected+x));
```